# Error while getting properties from object which was passed through the @Input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have created a simple array of objects in `app.component.ts`:

```
 zippyPost = [
      { title: 'Shipping Details',subtitle: 'Shipping Details Content' },
      { title: 'Billing Details',subtitle: 'Billing Details Content' }
  ]
```

Which is pass to the `zippy component` in `app.componenet.html` like:

```
<zippy-element [post] = "zippyPost"></zippy-element>
```

Then in `zippy.html` I have some logic to display `title` and `subtitle`. But I'd like to take a `title` property from `zippy component` which looks:

```
export class ZippyElementComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges  {
  @Input('post') post: any;
  expand: boolean;

  constructor() { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

   ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
    console.log('hello', changes.post.currentValue);
  }

  expanded(title : string){
    console.log('mmm', this.post)
    for(let i in this.post){
      if(title === i.title){ <- here it is an error which says : [ts] Property 'title' does not exist on type 'string'.
        console.log('im in if');
        this.post['ok'] = true;
      }
    }
   // this.expand = !this.expand;
  }
```

How can I get to those properties?

Comment: I think you want to use `of` instead of `in` for the for statement.

Comment: Yeah it helps. By the way what is the diffrence?

Comment: `of` iterates the values of an array, and `in` iterates the keys.

Comment: `this.post['ok'] = true;` makes no sense, `post` is an array in your example.